# How to convert file names using Bash/terminal

Tags: bash, rename

I have a bunch of files.

```
academic-cap.svg         arrow-narrow-right.svg   
ban.svg                  chart-bar.svg
adjustments.svg          arrow-narrow-up.svg      
beaker.svg               chart-pie.svg
...
...
```

I'd like to change

1. the first letter and after the dashes to uppercase
2. remove dashes
3. add Icon at the end
4. change the file name to svelte.

```
AcademicCapIcon.svelte   ArrowNarrowRightIcon.svelte   
BanIcon.svelte           ChartBarIcon.svelte
...
```

How can I do using Bash script or terminal.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Perl-base `rename` utility (sometimes also caled `prename`):

```bsh
rename -n 's/./\U$&/;s/-(.)/\U$1/g;s/\.svg$/Icon.svelte/' -- *.svg
```

The above command applies three Perl substitution operations on each name in the current directory matching the filename globbing pattern `*.svg`.

The first substitution, `s/./\U$&/`, replaces the very first character of the filename with the upper-case variant of itself.

The second substitution, `s/-(.)/\U$1/g`, replaces each occurrence of a character following a dash with the upper-case variant of that character while the dash is removed.

The last substitution, `s/\.svg$/Icon.svelte/`, replaces the `.svg` filename suffix with `Icon.svelte`.

The `-n` option to `rename` causes the filename transformations to be displayed but not carried out.  You may later change `-n` to `-v` to verbosely rename the files.

Example given the names in the question:

```bsh
$ ls
academic-cap.svg         ban.svg
adjustments.svg          beaker.svg
arrow-narrow-right.svg   chart-bar.svg
arrow-narrow-up.svg      chart-pie.svg
```

```bsh
$ rename -n 's/./\U$&/;s/-(.)/\U$1/g;s/\.svg$/Icon.svelte/' --  *.svg
rename(academic-cap.svg, AcademicCapIcon.svelte)
rename(adjustments.svg, AdjustmentsIcon.svelte)
rename(arrow-narrow-right.svg, ArrowNarrowRightIcon.svelte)
rename(arrow-narrow-up.svg, ArrowNarrowUpIcon.svelte)
rename(ban.svg, BanIcon.svelte)
rename(beaker.svg, BeakerIcon.svelte)
rename(chart-bar.svg, ChartBarIcon.svelte)
rename(chart-pie.svg, ChartPieIcon.svelte)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. It works like a charm.